# No auto build of QT Cmake project after update to VS 2019 16.11.1

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I've just update a Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.11.1 and my project stop to auto build when I try to debug it. I must run building before debuging on my own. I've checked my settings but everything looks ok. `Build when project is out of date` i sellect to `Always build`.
Have you got this problem before and have got any solution to that?
Was there any other setting, which can block auto build?

I work on Qt project using CMake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a bug was introduced in 16.11.1 (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/CMake-cache-generation-hangs-after-upg/1505033). Microsoft is aware of it and preparing a fix.